# JavaFX stage issue with hide and show Ask

Tags: javafx

i am just started to work with javafx and unable to hide the previous stage when click on button and open new stage. Here is my code

Also guide me is it better to develop a software in javafx

```
public void login(ActionEvent event) throws Exception
{
    try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress"+";databaseName=itapplication",usernametxt.getText(),passwordtxt.getText());
    Parent mainp = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Main.fxml"));
    mainpage(mainp);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        statuslbl.setText(e.getMessage());

    }

}
public void mainpage(Parent root) throws Exception
{
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    //Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("IT APPLICATION");
    stage.show();
}

public void addasset(ActionEvent event) throws Exception
{
    try {

        Parent asset = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Addasset.fxml"));
        mainpage(asset);
        /*Scene scene = new Scene(asset);
        addasset.setScene(scene);
        addasset.setTitle("IT APPLICATION");
        addasset.show();*/
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText(e.toString());
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Stage anyName= (Stage) (element of the stage you want to hide).getScene().getWindow();
anyName.hide();
```

You can call it right after you show the new stage.
If you want to know more add a comment.